# Unwrap symmetrical UV produces asymmetrical result

Tags: mesh, texturing, materials, uv, uv-image-editor

Unwrapping a symmetrical model seems to result in this asymmetrical mapping of the material/texture onto the model.

On the left, I have my unwrapped mesh, but on the right, I'm seeing a weird mapping pattern.

Am I missing something here?

Edit:

Additional note, I had to unwrap the head and the body separately (as in select head faces, unwrap, select body faces, unwrap, and then pack islands). If I select the whole mesh and select unwrap, the head unwrap produces an asymmetrical mesh.

[image: symmetrical mesh]

[image: asymmetrical mesh]

Comment: My best guess is: It's in the material setup, can you show us a screenshot of the node setup? You might have 2 UVMaps or the wrong texture input for your image.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That was exactly the problem - I had three UVMaps attached to the mesh. I deleted them all and created a new uvmap and was able to get it to map correctly.